# How to set active class on the current state using angular-route?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

my route file

```
app.config(["$routeProvider",function($route)
{
    $route.when("/",{
        templateUrl : "partials/index.html",
        controller : "AppCtrl"
    }).when("/contact",{
        templateUrl:"partials/contact.html",
        controller:"ContactCtrl"
    }).
    when("/about-us",{
        templateUrl:"partials/about.html",
        controller:"AboutCtrl"
    }).
    when("/gallery",{
        templateUrl:"partials/gallery.html",
        controller:"GalleryCtrl"
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo:"/"
    });

}]);
```

in my header.html partials i'm using HeaderCtrl controller

```
app.controller("HeaderCtrl",["$scope","$location",function($scope,$location)
{
    $scope.location=$location.path().replace("/","");
}]);
```

my header.html

```
<ul ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <li ng-class="{active:location===''}"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:location==='about-us'}"><a href="#/about-us">about us</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:location==='gallery'}"><a href="#/gallery">gallery</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:location==='contact'}"><a href="#/contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

when the page reloads (actual refresh) then it works ie the class active is applied on the respective li but when i change the routes (by clicking on the menu items) it doesn't work

Comment: That's because you aren't changing `$scope.location` in your controller when the route changes.

Comment: yup i think that is the case, how can i overcome this ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is to bind an event that updates `$scope.location` when the URL successfully changes. You don't have to bind a click event to each `<li>` element. What if the route is invalid or fails? You don't want to show the user that element is the active route when it's really not.

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) on the `$location` service, you'll see an events section. The one we're interested in is `$locationChangeSuccess`. To wire it up in your controller, do this:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
  $scope.location = $location.path().replace('/', '');
});
```

Comment: app.controller("HeaderCtrl",["$scope","$location","$locationChangeSuccess",function($scope,$location,$locationChangeSuccess)
{
 $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
   $scope.location = $location.path().replace('/', '');
 });
}]);

what blunder I did in this code ?

Comment: You do not need to inject `$locationChangeSuccess`. It is not a module. It comes as a part of the `$location` service. The code I posted is all you need to _add_ to your controller function.

Answer (score 0):

you add some object like active to router and set condition on your html with ngClass

like this :

```js
app.config(["$routeProvider",function($route)
    {
        $route.when("/",{
            templateUrl : "partials/index.html",
            controller : "AppCtrl",
            active:'home',
        }).when("/contact",{
            templateUrl:"partials/contact.html",
            controller:"ContactCtrl",
             active:'contact',
        }).
        when("/about-us",{
            templateUrl:"partials/about.html",
            controller:"AboutCtrl",
             active:'about',
        }).
        when("/gallery",{
            templateUrl:"partials/gallery.html",
            controller:"GalleryCtrl"
            active:'GalleryCtrl',
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo:"/"
        });

    }])
    //remember that add $route inside the scope 
    .controller("HeaderCtrl",["$scope","$location",function($scope,$route)
    {
      $scope.$route = $route;
      
    }]);
```

```css
.active{
  color:#a33;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <li data-ng-class="{'active':$route.current.active === 'home'}"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active':$route.current.active === 'about'}"><a href="#/about-us">about us</a></li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active':$route.current.active === 'gallery'}"><a href="#/gallery">gallery</a></li>
    <li data-ng-class="{'active':$route.current.active === 'contact'}"><a href="#/contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```